# Weird character imported in Qt QString from a system action in osx

Tags: c++, string, macos, qt, fonts

I have an app that at some point displays printer info.

On mac, when adding a printer, the default location is set as "me's iMac" unless user changes it. (me being the user name). But the apostrophe is not quite an apostrophe...

```
me’s iMac
```

[image: copied in notepad]

This is how it shows in system printer dialog:

[image: printer dialog mac]

When I try to display the location in my app - using

```
QString(pCups->getValue("printer-location", i))
```

I get

[image: on app]

How can I fix this substitution ? are they using a special font ? is there some way I can recognize it ?

I am thinking that if the user name contains other special characters, they may also be mapped to non-UTF-8 ones by the system add printer dialog. I don't have control over it... How can I find and fix any of the fancy symbols with standard ones ?

OSX 10.6-10.9

**edit**: for now I just did a replace with that specific character... But I think I may have other surprises if I don't do a more generic replace for all non-UTF-8 fancy characters

```
QString(pCups->getValue("printer-location", i)).replace("’", "'");
// this is what it looks like on Windows, though that particular item will only be used on unix (obviously... cups)
QString(pCups->getValue("printer-location", i)).replace("â€™", "'");
```

Comment: Stop using the fancified quote and use the ASCII quote (0x27).  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: How ? That quote is inserted by the mac system add printer. I want to replace it in my display with regular apostrophe. For now I simply did a "replace" and copy-pasted that symbol in my code... But I worry that there may be other such symbols, replacing a single one may not be enough. I wouldn't mind even replacing all non-ASCII characters with a space, just don't know how.

Comment: I don't use the mac, but be aware of the double quote and hyphen (minus sign).  It looks like the "add printer" suffers from the same thing as MS Outlook, and that is replacing ASCII characters with "fancy" ones that fall outside the 0-127 ASCII range.

Comment: Ok i will try to find and replace those two as well. Thanks...

Comment: What is the `pCups` object? Does it have a member function to specify the encoding or character set it should use? I'm sure the Mac APIs use Unicode to store the printer name. I don't know if that `getValue()` member function is returning UTF-8 or not. I don't know if the `QString` constructor is interpreting its argument as UTF-8 or not. From [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt), it seems that `QString` does not expect UTF-8 by default. You should either use `QString::fromUtf8()` or set the default encoding beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt), `QString` interprets its C-style string argument as Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1), not UTF-8. The advice given is to always construct `QStrings` from C-style strings using `QString::fromUtf8()` instead.

There's an alternative noted on that page, but you are discouraged from using it because it's a process-global setting and therefore may interfere with libraries or the like. You can call `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings()` passing the UTF-8 text codec (`QTextCodec::codecForName(“UTF-8”)`) early in the startup of your app.